# Remove Page Numbers, Tabular Data and Headings from a plain text file using python

Tags: python

I have a huge txt file from that I want to exclude every Page Number, Tabular Data or Headings. The only differentiator i can think of is that the Text I need to keep is at least two lines Long

The data does look (exemplary) like this:

```
1 C o mp a n y 

2 C o mb in ed ma na g emen t 

r ep o r t
```

```
Total equity and liabilities 

6,130.3 

100.0% 

5,930.0 

100.0% 

200.3
```

Additionally, there is bodytext, which I want to keep:

```
The total assets of ZALANDO SE rose by 3.4% primarily due to a further increase in financial 

assets. The assets of ZALANDO SE mainly consist of financial and current assets, specifically 

securities and cash, shares in affiliated companies as well as inventories and receivables. 

Equity and liabilities comprise equity and current and non-current liabilities and provisions.
```

I did try to write:

myvariable = textstring.replace(\n.*\n," ") but it does not do anything.

Comment: Are there any other indicators you have for which lines/sections you want to remove/keep? I don't think the information you've provided is quite sufficient

Comment: Unfortunately no, not as I am aware. The only differentiator i can think of is that the Text I need to keep is at least two lines Long.